# What does it mean when pgadmin 4 returns "No password or public key available!"?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I set up a remote database connection using an ssh tunnel with an identity file and password. I added localhost to connection hostname and added username and password for database access. When I click on save and connect now the program returns:

> No password or public key available!

What is pgadmin really trying to tell me here? I added all passwords and the identity file is selected from the local hard drive. So it is available. Does it mean the key file is not working??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private ssh keys come in two formats. PPK and PEM. If you work with e.g. AWS EC2 instances you will get a .pem file. If you work with putty/cygwin you will get a .ppk file.

The

> No password or public key available

error in pgAdmin means that you are trying to establish a ssh connection with a wrong key format.

With tools like **Puttygen** you can convert pem to ppk. There are multiple tutorials online for converting keys.

Comment: How about if one is using openSSH and the private key has no extension?

Comment: @Reddspark The extension of the file hardly matters but the format of the file. You can have any extension you like, as long as it's PEM formatted. Something like using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -b 4096 ....`.

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of PGAdmin4 you can configure SSH-tunnel (there is a tab for this there, but you need to use key in PEM format, not in RFC4716 that is now generated by default with `ssh-keygen`.

Use

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096
```

More information [here](https://t0ha.ru/en/faq/software/2019/06/05/faq-how-to-connect-pgadmin4-to-db-through-ssh-tunnel-with-public-key-authentication.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer)